# Find $2\times3$ matrix $A$ based on two equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find $2\times3$ matrix $A$ based on the following two equations:

\begin{align}
A[1,0,1]^T &= [2,8]^T;\\
A[1,1,1]^T &= [6,3]^T.
\end{align}

Well I know that those $[1,0,1]^T,[1,1,1]^T$ are linearly independent. And I assume I can see that question as a linear transformation from $R^3$ to $R^2$.

And I believe too that if I write $A = \begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \\ d&e&f\end{pmatrix}$ I will solve it.

**Edit:** Just found $b,e$ didn't succeed finding the others yet.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(1,1,1)=(6,3)$ and $A(1,0,1)=(2,8)$

This says $A(0,1,0)=(4,-5)$

For writing  a $2\times 3$ matrix you need three independent vector images.. You have only two...

You have $A(1,0,1)=(2,8)$.. Randomly set that $A(1,0,0)=(1,4)$ and $A(0,0,1)=(1,4)$ then you have

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&4&1\\4&-5&4\end{bmatrix}$$

You can check that 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&1\\4&-5&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&1\\4&-5&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\8\end{bmatrix}$$

As i have said previously, there are infinitely many $A$...